# Perform 2D vertices rotation in update function or render function

Tags: rotation, 2d, vertices

I'm starting to build a 2D game and have some confusion around whether I should perform rotation in the update function or the render function.

The problem is this;

I have a triangle, consisting of three vertices. The triangle has a rotation value in degrees.

If I rotate the vertices in the update function, the triangle rotates forever because each update applies the rotation over and over.

Therefore, I decided to not rotate the vertices in the update function and instead perform the rotation, based on the original vertices, in the render function.

This works, however now I have a different problem. The vertices are not actually where they appear to be. Therefore I can not use the vertices to perform collision detection, etc.

The only idea that I have to resolve this is that I could perform the rotation in the update function but have two sets of vertices; one for the original vertices, one of the rotated vertices. Then use the rotated vertices in collision detection calculations - this smells hacky and inefficient though!

I've put together a codepen demonstrating applying rotation in the render function; https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pPRjLq

```
Use arrow keys to rotate
```

So, should I rotate in render or update? If render then how do I keep vertices up to date? If update then how do I prevent infinite rotations?

Any help from experienced people would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have the rotation occur in the `update` method as you are updating the rotation of the actor.

You do not need to remember two vertices either, it would be a better alternative to just have current vertices of the actor and the rotation in radians, original vertices do not need to be remembered.

Thinking ahead, collision detection should not be dependent on the position vectors of an actor, better yet still, have a rectangle/AABB defined for it instead, which would need to be updated/scaled when rotation is applied to the actor.

If you did use a custom AABB for detection it could be set to the position of the actor vector by default, but by separating the constructs it opens up a lot of potential such as changing actor hit bounds x/y/width/length at run-time; it should not be coupled with actor x/y/width/height which should relate to the graphical representation of it.

To stop the infinite rotation you could have a `boolean` to state if left key up and one similarly for the right key, and something like below;

```
update(delta) {

   if(keyLeftDown) {
      // apply rotation as  rotation * delta / desiredFPS
   } else if (keyRightDown) {
      //
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.